# lost checked data when list expended group collection android

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

hi I have a ExpandableListView view that the child item have a check box. 
when i check or unchecked child item it work good but when i collect group
i lose my checked item and it restored to begin.

child.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/childname"
         android:paddingLeft="50px"
         android:focusable="false"
         android:textSize="14px"
         android:textStyle="italic"
         android:layout_width="150px"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/rgb"
         android:focusable="false"
         android:textSize="14px"
         android:textStyle="italic"
         android:layout_width="100px"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/check1"
           android:focusable="false"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

group.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/groupname"
        android:layout_width="150px"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:paddingLeft="50px"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

</LinearLayout>
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="show data" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="@string/main_no_items" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Color.java

```
package com.test;

public class Color {
    public String color = null;
    public String rgb = null;
    public boolean state = false;

    public Color() {

    }

    public Color( String color, String rgb, boolean state ) {
        this.color = color;
        this.rgb = rgb;
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public String getRgb() {
        return rgb;
    }

    public boolean getState() {
        return state;
    }
}
```

ColorAdabter.java

```
package com.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ColorAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<String> groups;
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<Color>> colors;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ColorAdapter(Context context, 
                        ArrayList<String> groups,
                        ArrayList<ArrayList<Color>> colors ) { 
        this.context = context;
        this.groups = groups;
        this.colors = colors;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from( context );
    }

    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return colors.get( groupPosition ).get( childPosition );
    }

    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return (long)( groupPosition*1024+childPosition );  // Max 1024 children per group
    }

    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = null;
        if( convertView != null )
            v = convertView;
        else
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_row, parent, false); 
        Color c = (Color)getChild( groupPosition, childPosition );
        TextView color = (TextView)v.findViewById( R.id.childname );
        if( color != null )
            color.setText( c.getColor() );
        TextView rgb = (TextView)v.findViewById( R.id.rgb );
        if( rgb != null )
            rgb.setText( c.getRgb() );
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)v.findViewById( R.id.check1 );
        cb.setChecked( c.getState() );
        return v;
    }

    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return colors.get( groupPosition ).size();
    }

    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return groups.get( groupPosition );        
    }

    public int getGroupCount() {
        return groups.size();
    }

    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return (long)( groupPosition*1024 );  // To be consistent with getChildId
    } 

    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = null;
        if( convertView != null )
            v = convertView;
        else
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_row, parent, false); 
        String gt = (String)getGroup( groupPosition );
        TextView colorGroup = (TextView)v.findViewById( R.id.groupname );
        if( gt != null )
            colorGroup.setText( gt );
        return v;
    }

    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    } 

    public void onGroupCollapsed (int groupPosition) {} 
    public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {}


}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ExpandableListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ExpandableListActivity
{
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "ElistCBox2";
    private ColorAdapter expListAdapter;

    Button b;
    ArrayList<String> groupNames;
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Color>> colors;
    ArrayList<Color> color;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
    {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);


        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                for (int i = 0; i < groupNames.size(); i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < colors.get(i).size(); j++) {
                        if (colors.get(i).get(j).state == true) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(groupNames.get(i)) + " "+  String.valueOf(j+1), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });



        groupNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        groupNames.add( "grey" );
        groupNames.add( "blue" );
        groupNames.add( "yellow" );
        groupNames.add( "red" );
        colors = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Color>>(); 
        color = new ArrayList<Color>();
        color.add( new Color( "lightgrey","#D3D3D3", false ) ); 
        color.add( new Color( "dimgray","#696969", true ) ); 
        color.add( new Color( "sgi gray 92","#EAEAEA", false ) );
        colors.add( color );
        color = new ArrayList<Color>();
        color.add( new Color( "dodgerblue 2","#1C86EE",false ) );
        color.add( new Color(  "steelblue 2","#5CACEE",false ) ); 
        color.add( new Color( "powderblue","#B0E0E6", true ) );
        colors.add( color );
        color = new ArrayList<Color>();
        color.add( new Color( "yellow 1","#FFFF00",true ) );
        color.add( new Color( "gold 1","#FFD700",false ) ); 
        color.add( new Color( "darkgoldenrod 1","#FFB90F", true ) );
        colors.add( color );
        color = new ArrayList<Color>();
        color.add( new Color( "indianred 1","#FF6A6A",true ) );
        color.add( new Color( "firebrick 1","#FF3030",false ) ); 
        color.add( new Color( "maroon","#800000", false ) );
        colors.add( color );

        expListAdapter = new ColorAdapter( this,groupNames, colors );
        setListAdapter( expListAdapter );
    }

    public void onContentChanged  () {
        super.onContentChanged();
        Log.d( LOG_TAG, "onContentChanged" );
    }

    public boolean onChildClick(
            ExpandableListView parent, 
            View v, 
            int groupPosition,
            int childPosition,
            long id) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "group is: " + String.valueOf(groupPosition) +"\nchild is: " + String.valueOf(childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d( LOG_TAG, "onChildClick: "+childPosition );
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)v.findViewById( R.id.check1 );
        if( cb != null )
            cb.toggle();
        return false;
    }
}
```

when i click button i see all item that I selected.

tank you.

Comment: do you receive any errors or in the console? or only the undesired behavior you describe?

Comment: @Clayton my cheched list dont saved only

Answer (score 0):

I fix it

```
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

    Toast.makeText(
            Listsefaresh_Activity.this,
            "group is: " + String.valueOf(groupPosition) + "\nchild is: "
                    + String.valueOf(childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onChildClick: " + childPosition);
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxchilditem);
    if (cb.isChecked() == true) {
        colors.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition).state = false;
    }
    else {
        colors.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition).state = true;
    }       if (cb != null)
        cb.toggle();
    return false;
}
```